# Why isn't my program able to read a string with gets function and it passed throught it and gives me just the final results of the earlier scanfs

Tags: c, gets, string.h

So this is a program where I want to input the asked variables from student 1 to student 2(school number, average grade, year of entrance and the alumns course), and I have to use a lib file, which I named alumn.h, where I have the typdef struct and the function copyAlumn which will copy from the input sturct ALUMN and return it's values to the second one. The thing is, in console everything works fine except reading it's String: when I use *gets* function it's will automatically pass it throught and give me the printed result.
What's my error?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include"alumn.h"

int main(){

    ALUMN A1,*A2;


    printf("Alumn A1:\nInsert the alumn number: ");
    scanf("%d",&A1.num);
    printf("Insert the year of entrance: ");
    scanf("%d",&A1.year);
    printf("Insert its avg. grade: ");
    scanf("%f",&A1.grade);
    printf("Insert its course: ");
    gets(A1.course);

    A2 = copyAlumn(&A1);

    if(A2 == NULL)
        return 0;

    printf("\n\nAlumn A2 = Copy from A1:\nNumber: %d\nYear: %d\nAvg. Grade: %.2f\nCourse: %s\n",A2->number,A2->year,A2->grade,A2->course);
return 1;
}
```

You might find some bad tagged functions in the code as I've just translated it to english, and some I might have passed throught without changing. I believe that's not the problem ofc.
Sorry for my bad english, as you can see it's not my main language...
Thanks in advance!

--EDIT--
As asked in the comments, here is the Alumn.h file code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef struct{
    int num;
    int year;
    char course[30];
    float grade;
}ALUMN;

ALUMN *copyAlumn(ALUMN *A){
    ALUMN *B;

    B = (ALUMN *)malloc(sizeof(ALUMN));

    if(B==NULL)
        return NULL;

    //*B=*A;
    (*B).num=(*A).num;
    (*B).year = (*A).year;
    (*B).grade = (*A).grade;
    strcpy((*B).course,(*A).course);

    return B;
}
```

Comment: OT: the function: `gets()` has been depreciated for years and completely removed from the C language in recent versions of the code.   Your compiler should have told you this.  Suggest using `fgets() (read the MAN page for the details

Comment: OT: regarding: this kind of statement: `(*B).num=(*A).num;`  It is much clearer to write: `B->num = A->num;`

Comment: OT: regarding: `B = (ALUMN *)malloc(sizeof(ALUMN));`  in C, the returned type is `void *` which can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest removing the cast.

Comment: OT:  in general, returning 0 indicates success and returning anything else from `main()` indicates an error occurred.  Suggest swapping the ``return 0;` and the `return 1;` statements

Comment: Mixing `fgets` (or the deprecated `gets`) and `scanf` is a bad idea. It can work but is really error prone because `scanf` leaves and end of line that will immediately terminate the next `fgets`. Chose one method and stick to it.

Comment: do not place .C code in a header file.  Rather write a second .c file. compile each separately, then link them together.  The current .h file needs little more than the prototype for the `CopyAlumn()` function

Comment: OT: regarding this kind of statement: `scanf("%d",&A1.num);`  Always check the return value  (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful. (in this case anything other than 1 indicates an error occurred)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

> ```
> scanf("%f",&A1.grade);
> printf("Insert its course: ");
> gets(A1.course);
> ```

when you enter the value for *grade* you finished it by a newline (e.g. `12.23<enter>`) the part *12.23* is used by *scanf* and the newline still present in the input is get by *gets* who returns an empty string

is a bad idea to mix *scanf* and *gets*

---

you can replace

> ```
> printf("Alumn A1:\nInsert the alumn number: ");
> scanf("%d",&A1.num);
> printf("Insert the year of entrance: ");
> scanf("%d",&A1.year);
> printf("Insert its avg. grade: ");
> scanf("%f",&A1.grade);
> printf("Insert its course: ");
> gets(A1.course);
> ```

by

```
char s[16];

printf("Alumn A1:\nInsert the alumn number: ");
if ((fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin) == NULL) ||
    (sscanf(s, "%d",&A1.num) != 1)) {
  /* indicate error */
  return -1;
}

printf("Insert the year of entrance: ");
if ((fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin) == NULL) ||
    (sscanf(s, "%d",&A1.year) != 1)) {
  /* indicate error */
  return -1;
}

printf("Insert its avg. grade: ");
if ((fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin) == NULL) ||
    (sscanf("%f",&A1.grade) != 1)) {
  /* indicate error */
  return -1;
}

printf("Insert its course: ");
if (fgets(A1.course, sizeof(A1.course), stdin) == NULL) {
  /* indicate error */
  return -1;
}
```

as you see I use *fgets* rather than *gets* to be sure to not go out of the string with an undefined behavior

Comment: So, what's the best option for me in this case? What should I use so I don't get this kind of error

Comment: @PakitoGama the best case is to always do _fgets_ and when needed _sscanf_, I will edit my answer ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I came across my teacher and he told me I should've used a fflush, which will clear the input right before the _gets_ function. This way it seemed to work as well.

Comment: @PakitoGama warning _fflush_ doesn't work in a lot of cases, for instance does not work for _stdin_, so this is *not* the solution. Your teacher is wrong, this is a pity :-(